# Save and restore terminal content

Tags: linux, terminal, ansi-escape

I am writing automation scripts (`perl`/`bash`). Many of them benefit from some basic terminal GUI. I figured I'd use standard `ANSI` sequences for basic drawing. Before drawing in terminal I do `clear` but doing that I lose some terminal command history. I want to be able to restore terminal command history when my program exists. Many terminal programs (e.g. `less`, `man`, `vim`, `htop`, `nmon`, `whiptail`, `dialog` etc) do exactly that. All of them restore terminal window bringing the user back to where he was prior to calling the program with all the history of commands previously executed.

To be honest I don't even know where to start searching. Is it a command from `curses` library? Is it an `ANSI` escape sequence? Should I mess with `tty`? I am stuck and any pointers would be really helpful.

EDIT: I'd like to clarify that I am not really asking "how to use the alternative screen". I am looking for a way to preserve terminal command history. One possible answer to my question could be "**use** alternative screen". The question "what is alternative screen and **how to use it**" is a **different** question which in turn already has answers posted elsewhere. Thanks :)

Comment: This should solve your problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/how-to-configure-screen-restore-in-a-terminal It's an xterm feature. Not every terminal supports it. Linux console (what you get in virtual consoles) does not.

Comment: @PSkocik This looks like what I was looking for. An escape sequence after all. Thanks! You can post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the "alternate screen" in a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/using-the-alternate-screen-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: They are different questions though. This question may have multiple different answers, one of which is "use alternative screen". The other question is "how to use the alternative screen".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the ***alternate screen*** terminal capability. See
[Using the "alternate screen" in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/using-the-alternate-screen-in-a-bash-script)

## An answer to *"how to use the alternate screen"*:

### This example should illustrate:

```
#!/bin/sh
: <<desc
Shows the top of /etc/passwd on the terminal for 1 second 
and then restores the terminal to exactly how it was
desc

tput smcup #save previous state

head -n$(tput lines) /etc/passwd #get a screenful of lines
sleep 1

tput rmcup #restore previous state
```

This'll only work on a terminal has the `smcup` and `rmcup` capabilities (e.g., not on Linux console (=a virtual console)).
Terminal capabilities can be inspected with `infocmp`.

On a terminal that doesn't support it, my `tput smcup` simply return an exit status of 1 without outputting the escape sequence.

---

**Note:**

If you intend to redirect the output, you might want to write the escape sequences directly to `/dev/tty` so as to not dirty your `stdout` with them:

```
exec 3>&1 #save old stdout
exec 1>/dev/tty #write directly to terminal by default
#...
cat /etc/passwd >&3 #write actual intended output to the original stdout
#...
```

Comment: linux virtual console seems to have this feature now :)