# Making bash on ungraphical debian look neat and tidy, like when sshing to it

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, debian

OH GOD I'M SUCH A NOOB
wait let me explain this.

I am somewhat familiar with linux, and i own a raspberry pi which i use as a ssh server, but i recently got hold on a old Dell Precision M4300 Laptop, so i got a minimal debian installation on that as well.

Howerver, as i logged in directly (as using the display and keyboard on the machine) to the laptop, i discovered a strange thing:

When executing a command resulting in a new menu, for example

```
nano .bashrc
```

, and than exiting that menu, the output gets shown where previously only the list of typed in commands and outputs was. This seems somewhat logical, as the "menue" is a "command output" as well, but when sshing to the machine from my windows machine (via gygwin or putty), the "menue" closes and i see the list of prompts and command outputs again, the same happens when sshing to the raspi. Is this a speciality of Putty / Cygwin? Can i make bash on the machine clean up after nano?

Thanks for any replys, i am really out of ideas here, i don't even know the right search term...

Comment: I have a bad imagination, so can you copy and paste what you are seeing between the two so I can get a clear understanding. Maybe everyone else can picture what you are explaining better, but I think it would help me help you, seeing  exactly what you are referring to.

Comment: Are you saying that when you open and close the editor, the text from the file is appearing over all of your previous commands?

Comment: Could you just `nano .bashrc ; clear`? Or do you want the screen to continue showing all the previous commands etc?

Comment: Google for "alternate screen".

Comment: @bluerojo, yes, this is exactly what happens, and yes, i would like it to continue showing all the previous commands

Comment: @julian & chepner, i do not want to install screen for this :(

Comment: are you running xterm? gnome-terminal?

Comment: if you are running gnome, how about `gnome-terminal -x bash-c "nano ~/.bashrc; bash"`

Comment: `gnome-terminal -x bash -c "nano ~/.bashrc"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are talking about is implemented by `smcup` and `rmcup` which can be used by editors such as nano and other applications to save and restore the screen when they are invoked and exited. This functionality is known as `alternate screen` and you can find more documentation regarding it [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes). Some people actually are [quite annoyed by it](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/AlternateScreenPlague).

Unfortunately, if you're using the [linux virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) instead of X windows or even connecting into the machine via ssh from another computer, then it seems like this feature is not available, according to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929816/save-and-restore-terminal-content/33942596#33942596).

Comment: That explains why the same machine acts different when displaying stuff over ssh (from an xterm terminal, as cygwin seems to be), thank you!

Comment: Also this means that i can switch this behaviour back and fourth when using a graphical linux install (and therefore xterm or soemthing like that...)