# bash, reset terminal output as it was before

Tags: linux, bash

I'm building a bash script, with an interactive ASCII-menu, and want it to restore the terminal as it was before, like "vim" does, or "less".

I guess, i have to redirect the output to an other shell or something like that. But all I have found, was for redirecting files, or opening new terminal windows.

Comment: Not an answer... but relevant... http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60533/how-does-man-restore-the-screen-when-i-quit-the-program. It appears as though this functionality is a feature of the terminal emulator and not of bash itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/using-the-alternate-screen-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Do you mean restoring terminal *content*?

Comment: @Lix thank you, thats what I was searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `ti` and `te` terminal capabilities, which can be most easily accessed in bash (or on the command line) with the commands `tput smcup` to switch to the alternate screen and `tput rmcup` to restore the original screen.

Comment: Nice - didn't realise it was this simple to do.  Adding to scripts for a little pizzaz :)

Comment: thank you, I'm searching this for days now.