# Is it settings in .vimrc, .bashrc or .screenrc which prevent vi to show the editing window after exiting?

Tags: bash, vim, terminal, vi

When I type vim filename, vim opens and I edit the file. When I close it, the part of file that was present on the display while I was in vim still shows up at the display, and all the previous terminal display gets scrolled up. How to make sure that When I close the file, the complete text from the file is gone , and I see the teminals' command/output that was previously present ?

I saw a lot of answers for this question already, and i tried the following things (but none of them is working) :

1) **export TERM=xterm** in [.bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60499/how-to-set-the-bash-display-to-not-show-the-vim-text-after-exit)

2) **altscreen on** in [.screenrc](https://superuser.com/questions/189051/gnu-screen-removing-vim-window-after-quit)

3) **set t_ti=""** in [.vimrc](https://superuser.com/questions/196055/how-to-replace-vim-screen-buffer-with-previous-bash-activity-after-quitting)

I tried all these things, even tried without screen but none of them is working. Can anyone let me know how to solve this issue ? Also let me know if it is the settings in .vimrc or .screenrc or .bashrc which affect this behaviour and under what conditions (if we have these settings in all the 3 files which will take precedence) ? Any pointers to links/docs explaining this will be really useful.

Comment: Clearing `t_ti` in vim sounds like it would do the opposite of what you want.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/using-the-alternate-screen-in-a-bash-script for more information.

Comment: @melpomene : i have commented 'set t_ti="" ' now, but even then this value is cleared by default when i check using 'echo $t_ti '. Can you please let me know to what value t_ti should be set to then.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using (is it actually xterm or something else)?

Comment: @melpomene i have set "export TERM=xterm" in my .bashrc file

Comment: Irrelevant. What terminal emulator are you actually using?

Comment: @melpomene : i am using putty to ssh into my freebsd VM. And the issue comes even if i remove my .vimrc, .screenrc & .bashrc files. So it is some default setting somewhere which is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD has altscreen disabled by default in "xterm". But they provide "xterm-clear" with the setting enabled:

```
export TERM=xterm-clear
```

Comment: Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328290/how-to-hide-fullscreen-cli-program-output-in-xterm-on-freebsd/516401

Answer (score -1):

In `vim`, you also need to set `t_te`:

```
set t_ti= t_te=
```

Comment: i added the above line in .vimrc, but still the issue remains as it is. please let me know if there is anything else that i can try.