# How to get an overlay output for a command in terminal like less or man?

Tags: terminal, ncurses, xterm

Some of the linux commands like `less` or `man` display their output in the current terminal occupying the whole screen. But the previous interactions reappear as is once the program quits.

How can we achieve the same behavior for our custom program?

Thank you.

Comment: Got it working easily using `tput` mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11024208/1897481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, **`less`** and **comparable** programs use a *termcap* interface which could be provided by various libraries.  The point of the question asked how the "previous interactions" could be restored.  That is a feature of xterm and other programs called the *alternate screen*, which conventionally is used via the terminal *capabilities* for starting and ending *cursor-addressing* mode.  The feature is completely terminal-dependent (ncurses only provides the information).

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite) (xterm FAQ)
- [Types of library users](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library) (ncurses FAQ)

Comment: Thank you! The first link led me to look for termcap and that led me to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11024208/1897481). From there, using `tput` I was able to get it working.