# xtermjs, few questions regaring the usage

Tags: terminal, pty, xtermjs

Struggling to get using [xtermjs](https://xtermjs.org/), and have some questions which aren't covered in the official documentation, at least I didn't find.

1. I understand that when I use some app within the terminal, for example, [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) terminal need to be switched to alternate buffer, after I quit from the app, terminal switched back to the normal buffer. Is this right?

---

2. To switch between buffers (and overall to control terminal behavior) I need to use a control sequence. It isn't something unique to xterm.js, but the common pattern and control sequence is unified between terminals?

---

3. Control sequence to switch to the alternate buffer is `CSI ? Pm h` with parameter `47` according to documentation:

> DECSET    DEC Private Set Mode    CSI ? Pm h  Set various terminal attributes.

Where

> `paramAction` 47 - Use Alternate Screen Buffer.

---

4. How to use this control sequence with xterm.js, for example, I want to switch to alternate buffer. What string should be used in `terminal.write(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, see description here in this question [Using the “alternate screen” in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/using-the-alternate-screen-in-a-bash-script)

   > The alternate screen is used by many "user-interactive" terminal applications like vim, htop, screen, alsamixer, less, ... It is like a different buffer of the terminal content, which disappears when the application exits, so the whole terminal gets restored and it looks like the application hasn't output anything
2. Yes, [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

   > ANSI escape sequences are a standard for in-band signaling to control the cursor location, color, and other options on video text terminals and terminal emulators. Certain sequences of bytes, most starting with Esc (ASCII character 27) and '[', are embedded into the text, which the terminal looks for and interprets as commands, not as character codes.
3. - Control sequence to switch to alternate buffer: `CSI ? 47 h`
   - Control sequence to switch to regular buffer: `CSI ? 47 l`
4. Code to apply control sequence to switch to alternate buffer:

```
terminal.write("\x9B?47h"); //CSI ? 47 h
```